# Reading custom metrics from the last build for custom baseline comparisons

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm planning to introduce linting into a rather massive code base. Fixing all existing issues beforehand is not possible, so seeing thousands of linter errors at start is inevitable.

I'd like to record the number of detected errors each time the build runs for master and treat this number as a success / failure threshold. If a new pull request does not exceed the current baseline, its pipeline passes and so the proposed change is good to go. However, if the number of errors increases, I'd like the pipeline to fail, thus preventing the merge.

This functionality I’ve described narrows down to writing variables to Azure DevOps servers as some side-effects of builds and also reading these values from the *previous* build. This looks very similar to [comparing code coverage](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mspremier.BuildQualityChecks&targetId=60499a5d-bf9a-40b2-af4f-a7081b9bed0f), however, I can't seem to find any docs on how to implement the read-write logic manually.

What pipeline task could I use? What else can I leverage to track a custom metric over a number of builds and compare the value with previous? To summarise, my ultimate goal is to gradually lower an arbitrary value from a large number to zero over the course of several months.

Comment: You're probably looking at creating a custom task here and storing your baseline as a custom artifact (json file) to the master build. The retrieve it through the Build Artefact REST API.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a separate static analysis/linting tool like SonarQube.

Comment: @DanielMann Adding extra tools to the CI/CD pipelines is evil IMO, as each of them is a single point of failure. The API of Azure DevOps does seem to support what I need, it's just not as easily accessible as I'd like it to be.